# SoundPool invalidates FileDescriptor sometimes?

Tags: android, audio, soundpool

I would like load the same sound asset twice, once with SoundPool and once with MediaExtractor.  My approach so far has been to give the same FileDescriptor to both SoundPool and MediaExtractor.  However, when I do this, sometimes the MediaExtractor rejects the FileDescriptor.  It's as if the asynchronous process that loads the sound for SoundPool invalidates it at some point.

Can I load from the same FileDescriptor twice somehow?

Comment: If it's the same underlying file descriptor, then if one class seeks to a new offset the other class won't find the header it's expecting. Can you open the asset twice, getting two different FileDescriptor objects for the same asset?

Comment: Hi Fadden, thanks for getting back to me.  I'd prefer if I could do this inside a function that takes only (FileDescriptor fileDescriptor, long offset, long length).  That way I can use that function no matter what the origin of the FileDescriptor is.  I would be happy with a solution where MediaExtractor reads the entire contents of the file, then seeks to the beginning and lets SoundPool read it again.  Or if I could to use one FileDescriptor to generate another FileDescriptor with the same data in it.  Is that possible?

Comment: After doing some more debugging, I'm convinced that the problem I'm isn't a race between MediaExtractor and SoundPool but rather, a race with garbage collection.  I've made a new, more focused post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879831/garbage-collection-invalidates-filedescriptor